# Yarn Workspaces: ENOENT: no such file or directory node_modules/.bin/jest during deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Since moving over to use Yarn Workspaces, I’m getting the following error when trying to deploy.

The serverless.yml file sits in the root of my graphql package, so /packages/graphql.

Jest is installed to the root node_modules folder and then symlinked to the root: node_modules/.bin/jest -> …/…/…/…/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.

```
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env.development:
Serverless:      - PORT
Serverless:      - DB_HOST
Serverless:      - DB_USER
Serverless:      - DB_PASSWORD
Serverless:      - DB_NAME
Serverless: Cleaning dependency symlinks
Serverless: Creating dependency symlinks
Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Using local tsconfig.json
Serverless: Typescript compiled.
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<redacted>packages/graphql/.build/node_modules/.bin/jest'
      at Package.getFileContent (<redacted root>/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/package/lib/zipService.js:134:15)
      at Package.getFileContentAndStat (<redacted root>node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/package/lib/zipService.js:123:12)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              10.15.3
     Framework Version:         1.54.0
     Plugin Version:            3.1.2
     SDK Version:               2.1.2
     Components Core Version:   1.1.1
     Components CLI Version:    1.2.3
```

Any idea why this would be happening?